# Clean R script to make it more streamlined

Tags: r, code-cleanup

I have some code that is being duplicated 24 times in order to take into account the different hours a day. 
I want to know of the possibility to streamline this code:

```
SBS00<-colSums(subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="00:00:00"|Total$Group=="SBS"))
SBS01<-colSums(subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="01:00:00"|Total$Group=="SBS"))
SBS02<-colSums(subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="02:00:00"|Total$Group=="SBS"))
SBS03<-colSums(subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="03:00:00"|Total$Group=="SBS"))
...
SBS23<-colSums(subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="23:00:00"|Total$Group=="SBS"))
```

So the general idea is to get 24 new variables SBS00 to SBS23.

When I have run that code, I will then need to combine these into a dataframe using this code:

```
SBS <- data.frame(SBS00,SBS01,SBS02,SBS03,...,SBS23)
```

Is there a possibility to clean that up as well?

I also have this piece of code that is in need of some streamlining:

```
SlopeSBS00<-lm(SBSNy$SBS00[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS01<-lm(SBSNy$SBS01[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS02<-lm(SBSNy$SBS02[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS03<-lm(SBSNy$SBS03[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
...
SlopeSBS23<-lm(SBSNy$SBS23[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
```

Here SBSNy is a transformed version of SBS from prior, and Numbers is a numbers vector from 1:41, so basically what this code does for each line is doing a linear regression of SBSNy for each SBS00 to SBS23, for the columns 1:10 and 17:41. Coeff[2] only exports the Slope which is needed here.

And finally I have a different code a little further down that also needs to be cleaned up, this looks like this:

```
Total$Base00 <- (Total$base + Total$base*dataval*11)
Total$Base01 <- (Total$base + Total$base*dataval*12)
Total$Base02 <- (Total$base + Total$base*dataval*13)
Total$Base03 <- (Total$base + Total$base*dataval*14)
...
Total$Base30 <- (Total$base + Total$base*dataval*41)
```

Giving me a total of 31 Base variables from 00 to 30.

This is also then followed up by this code:

```
Total$Uplift00 <- (Total$cols11 - Total$Base00)
Total$Uplift01 <- (Total$cols12 - Total$Base01)
Total$Uplift02 <- (Total$cols13 - Total$Base02)
Total$Uplift03 <- (Total$cols14 - Total$Base03)
...
Total$Uplift30 <- (Total$cols41 - Total$Base30)
```

I hope you can help as this would streamline my code a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sapply/lapply` to do this for multiple columns

```
 Hr <- sprintf('%02d:00:00',0:23)
 SBS <- do.call(cbind,lapply(Hr, function(x)
       colSums(subset(Total[14:54], Total$Hour==x & Total$Group=='SBS'))))
 colnames(SBS) <- sprintf('SBS%02d', 0:23)
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 Total %>% 
      filter(Group=='SBS') %>% 
      group_by(Hour) %>%
      summarise_each(funs(sum),14:54) %>% 
      select(-Hour) %>% 
      t()
```

Or using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
 T1 <- cbind(Total[c(14:54)], Total['Hour'])
 t(aggregate(.~Hour, T1, subset=Total$Group=='SBS', FUN=sum)[,-1])
```

For the 2nd case

```
 nm1 <- sprintf('Base%02d', 0:30) 
 Total[nm1] <- lapply(11:41, function(x) with(Total, base + base*dataval*x))
```

For 3rd

```
 nm2 <- sprintf('Uplift%02d', 0:30)
 Total[nm2] <- Total[paste0('cols',11:41)]-Total[nm1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:9, 54*100, replace=TRUE), ncol=54))
set.seed(39)
Total <- cbind(df1, Hour=sample(sprintf('%02d:00:00', 0:23), 100, 
   replace=TRUE), Group= sample(c('SBS', 'SBT', 'SBI'), 100, 
      replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 dataval <- 5
 colnames(Total)[1] <- 'base'
  colnames(Total)[11:41] <- paste0('cols', 11:41)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, 

I have tried testing the first part, and I get an error because Total[14:54] does not include Hour or Group, but only raw numbers as I want.

But when I change and include the whole Total, I get an error in that x is not a numeric value. So it does not treat Hr as a numeric variable?

Comment: @KhaliN I changed the code.  It should be `Total$Hour` and `Total$Group`

Comment: @KhalidN I have a doubt.  Can you check whether you need `&` instead of `|`.. i.e. `subset(Total[c(14:54)],Total$Hour=="00:00:00"&Total$Group=="SBS")`  Using your condition, it will also subset `Group` that is not equal to `SBS` and Hour!='00:00:00` as we are using the OR condition

Comment: You are right! it has to be & and not |, I was not aware of the difference. thanks for the heads up. 
I am in the process of testing the other code, I'll let you know if there is any problems along the way

Comment: I will do that as soon I have tested all the code through and through :)

I have some code that I thought I could fix with the guides you gave, but I am yet to do it correctly. Hope you can help.

It is the same pattern as before with this:

    SlopeSBS00<-lm(SBSNy$SBS00[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
    SlopeSBS01<-lm(SBSNy$SBS01[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
   ... to SlopeSBS23

I tried this without any luck
    HR <-sprintf('%02d',0:23)
    HR2 <-sprintf('SBS%02d',0:23)
SlopeSBS[HR]<-lm(SBSNy[HR2][c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]))

Comment: @KhalidN It is a separate code so it will go as another post.  Also, you didn't provide any reproducible example for me to test

Comment: I have added the code in the text, please have a look :)

Comment: Would you still be needing some data to be able to reproduce it?

Comment: I have added a new post in regards to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182761/code-cleanup-in-r

Comment: @KhalidN Looks like you got a solution for your new post.

Comment: I cannot get it to work, and I believe your solution with sprintf is much better?

Comment: @KhalidN As I mentioned earlier, a reproducible example will make it easier to test the code especially for your new question.   Could you update the other post with an example data just I like I showed here?

Comment: @KhalidN I did see that.  You are just using `...` to fill in the data.   It makes it difficult to test.