# Code cleanup in R

Tags: r, code-cleanup

I have this piece of code that is in need of some streamlining:

```
SlopeSBS00<-lm(SBSNy$SBS00[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS01<-lm(SBSNy$SBS01[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS02<-lm(SBSNy$SBS02[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
SlopeSBS03<-lm(SBSNy$SBS03[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
...
SlopeSBS23<-lm(SBSNy$SBS23[c(1:10,17:41)] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2]
```

Here SBSNy is a transformed version of a variable SBS, which is normalized, and Numbers is a numbers vector from 1:41.
So basically what this code does for each line is doing a linear regression of SBSNy for each SBS00 to SBS23, for the columns 1:10 and 17:41. 
Coeff[2] only exports the Slope which is needed here.

**I forgot to add something**

The SlopeSBS00 to SlopeSBS23 needs to be combined into a data.frame:
something like this:
SlopeSBS <-data.frame(SlopeSBS00,SlopeSBS01,...,SlopeSBS23)

Much appreciated any form of guidance or help with this piece of code

**Data example**

SBSNy contains a data.frame with 41 observations and 25 variables:

```
Numbers    SBS00    SBS01    SBS02    ...    SBS23
1          1.600    1.735    1.644    ...    1.328
2          1.486    1.692    1.522    ...    1.301
3          1.421    1.597    1.370    ...    1.321
...        ...      ...      ...      ...    ...
41         1.286    1.395    1.182    ...    1.206
```

An example on a code to manufacture the data, although this data is with a range from 0-100:

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:100,24*41,replace=TRUE),nrow=41, ncol=24))
Numbers <-c(1:41)
SBSNy<-data.frame(Numbers,df1)
names(SBSNy)<-c("Numbers",sprintf('SBS%02d',0:23))
```

Comment: Try `data.frame(lapply(SBSNy[c(1:10,17:41),-1], function(x) lm(x~SBSNy$Numbers[c(1:10, 17:41)])$coef[2]))`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "SBS00" is your secont column on your data frame "SBSNy":

```
for (x in 1:23){
    if (x < 10){
    var <- paste0("SBS0", x)
    } else {
    var <- paste0("SBS", x)
    }

      assign(paste0("Slope", var), lm(SBSNy[c(1:10,17:41), x+1] ~ Numbers[c(1:10,17:41)])$coeff[2])
}
# Untested code
```